# Ember.js: Load related multiple models

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

Since the ember-guides explains how to load mutliple models on a route like that

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      songs: this.get('store').findAll('song'),
      albums: this.get('store').findAll('album')
    });
  }
});
```

Im wondering how to load only the related model-entries from a second one, like loading ALL songs but only the albums which are indexed in the songs if we assume that the song model containing this

```
...
albums: hasMany('album'),
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should sideload the albums along with the songs, or get the songs in the model hook and query the albums in the afterModel hook using the song ids you got from the model

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your adapter and JSON API backend support it, you can simply say:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      songs: this.get('store').findAll('song', { include: 'albums' }),
    });
  }
});
```

Typically, this will generate a `GET` to `/songs?include=albums`, which tells the JSON API backend to include the related album resources, according to http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes.

On the Ember side of things, this feature is documented at http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-finder-include-code.

If the above isn't an option, then there's no way to load everything in one request without building a custom endpoint and using `store.pushPayload`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      this.store.findAll('song').then(function(songs){
        var albumPromises = songs.map(fuction(s){return s.get('album')});
        Em.RSVP.all(albumPromises).then(function(){
           resolve(songs);
        });
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
});
```

So Basically you are waiting till everything is resolved.

Hope it helps!

Comment: songs.map(fuction(s){return s.get('album')});  -> Is this returning Promise?explanation required for your answers for better understanding.

Comment: yes s.get('album') will return promise because its a relationship which will be loaded later.